# Themed Application Guidelines

Tags: css, themes

I am creating HTML for an application that will be themed ("skinned") with CSS and background images. There could be a large number of themes used for the same web app. I was wondering what, if any, guidelines could be followed when creating the HTML so as to facilitate creating themes later.

One important consideration is the ability to add HTML components later (such as UI components) without changing the large number of existing CSS themes. So, the more generic components are added and styled from the beginning, the less the themes will have to modified later.

Any ideas you have on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

i'm also do the same thing just add the color themes to the web application(html page). i found something which is more useful to you

http://usman.it/free-responsive-admin-template/ .download and the check these template which have the dynamic themes changing using the jquery(charisma.js) and the css for the each themes

where in header you see a code

```
 <link id="bs-css" href="css/bootstrap-cerulean.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to change the themes dynamically. for the less css same as the css files. justr change the extension in charisma.js file as css to less extension